# Can BIOS mean UEFI?

Tags: bios, uefi

According to Wikipedia:

> Unified Extensible Firmware Interface (UEFI) is the successor to BIOS, aiming to address its technical shortcomings

But eg. then why does my Dell xps 9360 currently booting using UEFI offer only the option **BIOS Flash Update** and not **UEFI Flash Update**?  And it's not an isolated example, it seems commonplace that people are using the term "BIOS" update in situations involving UEFI enabled computers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UEFI is firmware for computers [developed and published by Intel](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/unified-extensible-firmware-interface/efi-specifications-general-technology.html). Unlike most BIOS firmware, UEFI firmware can be found on systems which are not in the [IBM PC compatible class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_PC_compatible).

> **Note:** Newer PCs that ship with UEFI still refer to it as the “BIOS” to avoid
>   confusing people who are used to a traditional PC BIOS. Even if your
>   PC uses the term “BIOS”, modern PCs you buy today almost certainly
>   ship with UEFI firmware instead of a BIOS.
>
> <sub>[source](https://www.howtogeek.com/56958/htg-explains-how-uefi-will-replace-the-bios/)</sub>

**Extensible Firmware**

UEFI is an extension of firmware like BIOS but <sup>(1)</sup>it can read from entries from disk partitions by not just booting from a disk but <sup>(2)</sup>booting from a specific boot loader in a specific location on a specific disk.

**Bootloader Compatibility for Execution by UEFI**

The [UEFI spec](http://www.uefi.org/specifications) defines the executable format requiring all UEFI firmwares to be capable of executing code in that format. When a bootloader is written for native UEFI, it is written in this format.

**Backwards Compatible**

For backward compatibility, most UEFI firmware can boot a system just like BIOS firmware and look for a MBR and run the boot loader from there as well. Depending on the firmware this may be called **BIOS legacy mode**, **BIOS compatibility mode**, or other similar terms.

> **Note:** UEFI is meant to replace the Basic Input/Output System (BIOS) firmware
>   interface, present in all IBM PC-compatible personal computers. In
>   practice, most UEFI images provide legacy support for BIOS services.
>
> <sub>[source](https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php?title=Some_basics_of_MBR_v/s_GPT_and_BIOS_v/s_UEFI)</sub>